# Date functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, column-alias

Task: display the customer names and their orders happened in Pune and Kolkata locations during March month

**Customers:**

```
CUST_ID    CUST_NAME    LOCATION
---------------------------------
   1          A         HYD
   2          B         PUNE
   3          C         DELHI
   4          D         KOLKATA
```

Orders:

```
ORDER_ID    CUST_ID AMOUNT  DATE
----------------------------------
100 3   1000    2019-03-22
101 2   2000    2019-03-12
103 1   3000    2019-04-11
104 2   5000    2019-04-10
105 3   6000    2019-02-18
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    c.cust_name, c.location,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), Date1, 100) AS Month
FROM
    customers1 c 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    orders o ON o.cust_id = c.cust_id
WHERE
    c.LOCATION = 'PUNE' OR c.LOCATION = 'KOLKATA'
GROUP BY 
    date1
HAVING
    Month = 'Mar'
```

I am getting this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Invalid column name 'Month'

Answer (score 3):

Can't refer to an alias name in your HAVING clause.  For performance reasons, I suggest filtering on the month number, instead of the month abbreviation.

```
SELECT
     c.cust_name
    ,c.location
    ,CONVERT(varchar(3), Date1, 100) as Month
FROM customers1 c
    INNER JOIN orders o on o.cust_id=c.cust_id
WHERE
    (c.LOCATION='PUNE' or c.LOCATION='KOLKATA')
WHERE
    MONTH(Date1) = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do does not work in SQL Server,  You cannot use a `SELECT` alias in a `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause (the way you are doing this).

Also, an outer join is not needed.  You can express what you want using `apply`:

```
select c.cust_name, c.location, v.month
from customers1 c join
     orders o
     on o.cust_id = c.cust_id cross apply
     (values (CONVERT(varchar(3), Date1, 100))) v(Month)
where c.LOCATION in ('PUNE', 'KOLKATA') and
      v.month = 'Mar';
```

I have no idea why you have `group by date1`.  `date1` is not in the `select` list and you have no aggregation functions, so the aggregation seems unnecessary.

Of course, I would simplify this to:

```
select c.cust_name, c.location, 
       left(datename(month, date1))
from customers1 c join
     orders o
     on o.cust_id = c.cust_idv(Month)
where c.LOCATION in ('PUNE', 'KOLKATA') and
      month(date1) = 3;
```

Comment: Seems silly to convert each date to a month abbreviation, and filter on that.  I'd filter on month number instead, and dump the APPLY( ).
`WHERE MONTH(Date1) = 3`